# R - Ellipse (`...`) and `NULL` in function parameters

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing, ellipse

Envision

```
examplefn <- function(x = NULL, ...){str(x)}
```

I'm trying to get this function to honor the implicit `x = NULL`. Consider the following:

For a call using both `x` and `...` this results as expected in:

```
> examplefn(1,2)
num 1
```

If using an explicit `x = NULL`, the behavior also is as expected:

```
> examplefn(x = NULL,2)
NULL
```

However, when attempting (and expecting the usage of `x = NULL` from the function definition, I get:

```
> examplefn(2)
num 2
```

Implying, that the call is evaluated by argument order, disregarding the `x = NULL` definition.

How can the latter be prevented?

Comment: `x = NULL` in the definition is a default value if `x` is missing. In `examplefn(2)` you basically set `x = 2`. You wish `x` to always be `NULL` and `examplefn(2)` to be equal to `examplefn(NULL,2)`?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal. I'm clearly not understanding the evaluation, but I was expecting the unnamed `2` to keep representing the ellipse ...

Comment: You might benefit from reading this section of the language definition (I even recommend reading the whole document): https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition `x = NULL` is only used if no `x` value is provided. So when writing `examplefn(2)` what `R` reads is `examplefn(x = 2)` (as `x` is argument number 1) and thus the result.

If you want to circumvent this, here are a few approaches:

**1.** By creating two functions

```
fun0 <- function (x, ...) str(x) 
fun1 <- function (...) fun0(NULL, ...)
fun1(2)
# NULL
```

**2.** Another approach is by naming you arguments, e.g.

```
fun2 <- function (x = NULL, y) str(x)
fun2(y = 2) 
# NULL
```

**3.** Another way, maybe the most convenient for you, is simply to reorder the arguments, see

```
fun3 <- function (..., x = NULL) str(x)
fun3(2)  
# NULL
```

**4.** Finally, here is also a (trivial) possibility - setting `x <- NULL` inside the function

```
fun4 <- function (...) {
  x <- NULL
  str(x)
}
fun4(2)    
# NULL
```

But I am assuming you have reasons to want `x` to be an argument.

Comment: 3. is indeed the most convenient. Thank you.

Comment: In my actual application, however, I'm loosing the option to pipe (`magrittr`) the x argument (it's a `list`) - if it's `NULL` it's created, modified if given ...