# R: Differentiating EMPTY ellipsis from one containing NULL?

Tags: r, ellipsis

Imagine:

```
myfunct <- function(x, ...){
  dots <- list(...)
...
}
```

How do I distinguish in the course of the function whether dots derived from `myfunct('something')` (no dots) or `myfunct('something', NULL)` (dots includes explicit `NULL`)?
In my experimentation both cases lead to `is.null(dots)` equating to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it help ?

```
f <- function(x, ...){
  missing(...)
}
> f(2)
[1] TRUE
> f(2, NULL)
[1] FALSE

g <- function(x, ...){
  length(list(...))
}
> g(2)
[1] 0
> g(2, NULL)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually came up with the following:

```
myfunct <- function(...)
{
  my_dots <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)[['...']]
  no_dots <- is.null(my_dots)
  # Process the dots
  if(!no_dots)
  {
     my_dots <- lapply(my_dots, eval)
  }
  # Exemplary return
  return(my_dots)
}
```

This yields:

```
> myfunct(1)
[[1]]
[1] 1

> myfunct(NULL)
[[1]]
NULL

> myfunct()
NULL

> myfunct(1, NULL, 'A')
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
[1] "A"
```